# How to vectorize in Eigen/C++: set columns under condition

Tags: c++, optimization, vectorization, eigen

I have a function `compute()` that takes as input
 a matrix `C` and output a matrix `X` of the same dimension, and does the following:

- For each column `C_j` of C, if the sum of its positive elements are less than or equal to 1, then the column `X_j` of `X` is the same as `C_j`, except that the non-positive elements are set to zeros, i.e. `X_j = C_j(C_j > 0)` (in Matlab language).
- Otherwise `X_j = f(C_j)` where `f` is some function. This part is not concerned in this question.

What I have tried so far.

```
MatrixXd compute(MatrixXd &C)
{
    // The matrix to return
    MatrixXd X(C.rows(), C.cols()); 

    // Thresholding C: if negative then set to 0
    MatrixXd P = (C.array() > 0).select(C, 0);

   // Compute the sum of each column of P (i.e. the 
   // sum of positive elements in C
   MatrixXd S = P.colwise().sum();

   // Now want to set all column X_j to P_j whenever S_j <= 1
   // I don't know how to vectorize this code
   // It's easy in Matlab: X(:, S <= 1) = P(:, S <= 1);
   for(int j = 0; j < S.cols(); j++){
    if(S(j) <= 1)
        X.col(j) = P.col(j);
   }
   return X;
}
```

For each column of `C`

Comment: What do you want to do with the columns whose sums are >1?

Comment: @Beta for the columns C_j whose sum (of positive elements) are > 1, X_j is the "projection of C_j onto the canonical simplex" (please Google the term).

Comment: But what do you want to do *in this part of the problem?* You seem to have a choice, either 1) apply the projection to all columns, then revert the columns whose sums were <=1, or 2) copy the entire matrix, then apply the projection to the columns whose sums are >1. The second approach sounds less expensive.

Comment: @Beta Oh yes, it's that simple, really. Just let X = P and then change the other columns after. Please post it as an answer. Thanks :D

Comment: It may solve your current problem, but it leaves the question unanswered-- and I don't know eigen well enough to answer it.

Comment: @Khue Why do you say `X(:, S <= 1) = P(:, S <= 1);` is vectorized in Matlab? Or are you referring to the nice short way it's written and not to SIMD instructions?

Comment: @AviGinsburg Yes I thought that in Matlab if it's short then it's optimized and fast :blushing: :shame:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest solution to your problem I found is this:

```
MatrixXd compute(const MatrixXd& C)
{
    MatrixXd P = C.cwiseMax(0.0); // cheaper than (...).select(C,0)
    RowVectorXd S = P.colwise().sum(); // colwise().sum() returns only one row
    MatrixXd X = (S.array()<=1).replicate(C.rows(), 1).select(P, 0.0);
    //      compare by 1 --^             ^               ^  
    // replicate result of comparison ---/               |
    //        select P or 0 depending on comparison  ----/
    return X;
}
```

Notice that neither comparisons nor `select` are currently (version 3.3rc2) vectorized in Eigen (but they eventually shall be, for any progress on that see http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=97).
That means that your current loop-implementation could actually be faster (which likely also depends on several other factors, like the size of your input).

Comment: Finally an Eigen guy :D I'll do benchmarking to see which one is actually faster. Your answer is very helpful (in particular, thanks for pointing out the .cwiseMax(.), I forgot it). Thanks a lot!!